# Assign value to sub-tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

Suppose I have a PyTorch tensor `t` of shape `(3, 3, 3, 3)`, and I want to set `t[0, 1, x, y]` to `z` for all `x` and `y`. I noticed all the following syntaxes work:

- `t[0, 1] = z`
- `t[0, 1, :] = z`
- `t[0, 1, :, :] = z`
- `t[0, 1, ...] = z`

Is there any difference in terms of how things are executed under the hood? Is any one of these methods preferred over the others?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference. You can benchmark it yourself and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in how `:` and `...` are [translated to C++](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html#translating-between-python-c-index-types) under the hood:

> The one-to-one translation between Python and C++ index types is as follows:
>
> | Python | C++ (assuming using namespace torch::indexing) |
> | --- | --- |
> | None | None |
> | Ellipsis | Ellipsis |
> | ... | "..." |
> | : or :: | Slice() or Slice(None, None) or Slice(None, None, None) |

Practically this has no effect on performance however. Use whichever style is most readable in your context.